# ADDRESPONSE ADDING TO MEMORY ONLY while using NSJSONSerialization

Tags: iphone, ios, json

Im getting this error that says ADDRESPONSE ADDING TO MEMORY ONLY. Im using a JSON link to load some keys and values.

This is the code:

```
NSString *str = @"http://jsonsite";
                           NSURL *linkJson = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:str];
                           jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:linkJson];
                           if (jsonData != nil)
                           {
                           NSError *error = [[NSError alloc]init];
                           NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
```

And i load the keys and values in these arrays,simpel as that:

```
news_Number = [dict valueForKey:@"NewsID"];
news_Date = [dict valueForKey:@"NewsDate"];
news_Title = [dict valueForKey:@"Titr"];
news_Image = [dict valueForKey:@"FileName"];
news_service = [dict valueForKey:@"RootServiceName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore this. This has nothing to do with your code. If you are interested what does this mean, it means that internal http loading mechanism has failed to cache your request's response. Good Luck!

Comment: you mean this is coming from the servers side and got nothin to do with my code? do i need to use cache?

Comment: No, it's not coming from the server, it's internal iOS error message. And, no you don't need to use cache, if your json response changes frequently and if it's not needed.

Comment: ok so there is no solution to this? actually i was reading jsons from some other website before this and everything worked fine. this error keeps showing up since i changed the source link.

Comment: Actually, there is a solution. Load your json data with `NSURLConnection` using `NSURLRequest`, and while creating `NSURLRequest` with `requestWithURL: cachePolicy: timeoutInterval:` method, specify cache policy as `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData` and you won't see this message again. If, this is hard for you, just ignore the message and continue coding. Good Luck!

Comment: ok ill try it out thanks for ur answer but i cant just ignore it. the app crashes when this error appears. thanks anyway ;)

Comment: On this error app doesn't crash. You need check your code for some other errors.

Comment: @FahriAzimov i tried your solution but im still getting the same error!

Comment: @FahriAzimov, nope - NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData is what i am using for NSMutableURLRequest for NSURLConnection and i do get the same diagnostic message.